# Gatling 2.0: Results in reports are inaccurate in 'group' method

Tags: gatling

I noticed that the results of my simulation does not seem to summed up. I have group the requests using '.group' method accordingly so it would be easier for analyzing the results of each action performed by a virtual user. Noticed that the Response time (ms) should show the following results:

1. 'Min' = 10ms rather than 4112ms
2. 'Max' = 666ms rather than 4112ms
3. '95th pct' = 95% of requests took no longer than 75ms. Hence is should display 75ms?

Please find the image here:
http://s23.postimg.org/wc0kqhrmj/Reports.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misunderstanding group [statistics](http://gatling.io/docs/2.0.1/general/timings.html#groups). What's reported in there is the group duration, not a view of the requests it contains. See documentation.